# join in spring data query repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

```
@Query("select u from User u join u.favoriteRestos s where u.id = ?1 ")
User findByIdWithFavoriteRestos (Long userId);
```

O have this query in the my repo, but instead of returning a User with empty favoriteRestos collection is returning a null user

that returns also a null user:

```
@Query("select u from User u join fetch u.favoriteRestos s where u.id = ?1 ")
User findByIdWithFavoriteRestos (Long userId);
```

I also tried with:

```
@Query("select u from User u left join u.favoriteRestos s where u.id = ?1 ")
User findByIdWithFavoriteRestos (Long userId);
```

Comment: You might need a left join otherwise if there are no favorite restos the join wouldn't yield any results.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that your input `id` value does not match any records in the underlying database table.  Check your data.

Comment: @Thomas I don't expect that a left join would change anything here, as the `WHERE` clause filters on the user table (which is on the left side of the join).

Comment: if thats an INNER JOIN then it can make the difference.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen "instead of returning a User with empty favoriteRestos" seems to indicate there is nothing to join the user with and thus an inner join (which it should be without any other keyword) would return an empty set (at least for that user).

Comment: @Thomas True for SQL, not true for Hibernate.  In HQL, even if the `favoriteRestos` collection be empty, the associated user entity should still be returned AFAIK.

Comment: If the given `id` exists in your database, then try it without join and any parameters, try something like `@Query("select u from User u where u.id = 12 ")`, 12 is an example, some id which exists in your database. I'm not sure, but sometimes the problem is not from the query at all :)

Comment: Should that be a `join fetch` instead of a `join` if you want to initialize the collection? See https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-difference-join-left-join-fetch-join/

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen well, the [JPA spec](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/jakarta-persistence-spec-3.0.html) states in `4.4.5.1. Inner Joins (Relationship Joins)`: "this type of join typically equates to a join over a foreign key relationship in the database." (so functionally equivalent to SQL) and in `4.4.5.2. Left Outer Joins`: "They enable the retrieval of a set of entities where matching values in the join condition may be absent." (the foreign key would be used in an implicit condition) - I agree with M. Deinum though: in the OP's case it should be a `JOIN FETCH`.

Comment: @Thomas A join fetch does _not_ affect the contents of the result set, but rather just means that if the relationship between `User` and favorites be lazy, then Hibernate will load the associated favorites during the query.  For one to one entities, fetch join would typically be the default behavior even sans the `fetch` keyword.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen exactly ... the OP's query and description look like the actual goal is to fetch the collection, i.e. get the user with id `x` and eagerly load any `favoriteRestos` that are there. So instead of just `JOIN` which influences the result set it should be `JOIN FETCH` which doesn't influence the result set.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen not if you do inner join.......

Comment: JOIN FETCH is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't find any user, because `join` is an inner join. You need to add `left` keyword:

```
@Query("select u from User u left join fetch u.favoriteRestos s where u.id = ?1 ")
User findByIdWithFavoriteRestos (Long userId);
```

P.S.: `fetch` is also needed if you have a default (lazy) to-many mapping if you want to populate the collection.